# reading registry and alert user if key found

Tags: vb.net, registry

I am new to VB and Visual Studio and was wondering if someone could help.

I am using a Visual Studio form application and a button to search the registry for multiple keys.

So far, with regards to the search, I have:

```
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test value NOT detected")
```

I know this is only searching for one key, but does anyone know how I can add "Item detected" if the key is found instead of if the key is not found as in my code above?

Note: I will have multiple search entries such as:

```
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test") Is Nothing Then    ListBox1.Items.Add("Test value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\TesT") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test3 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test4") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test4 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test5") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test5 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test6") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test6 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test7") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test7 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test8") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test8 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test9") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test9 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test10") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test10 value NOT detected")
If Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Test11") Is Nothing Then ListBox1.Items.Add("Test11 value NOT detected")
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the `else` statement? Or the `Not` operator?

Comment: Did try else but had this error Error 'Else' must be preceded by a matching 'If' or 'ElseIf'.

Comment: Are you putting `Else` on the same line as your if-statements above? Since you are using one line if-statements, the `Else` must go on the same line. Otherwise, please post the code using `Else` along with the exact error message.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks Daniel, I wasn't putting the 'else' on the same line.. simple!